# The default value is not ? object:null ? in select option Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

This is code in file js

```
$scope.ListOption = [];
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "0", Name: Car });
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "1", Name: House });
```

Here's what the code HTML looks like

```
<select class="form-control" id="Category" ng-model="Category">

<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="{{option.Value}}">
 {{option.Name}}</option>

</select>
```

The generated html is

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="Category" style="padding: 0px;">
<option value="? object:null ?"></option>
<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="0" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Car</option>
<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">House</option>
</select>
```

I have quite a headache on this issue. Looking forward to having someone help me the other way.

Comment: Should be using `ng-options` rather than `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's wrong. you are matching with `option`. Change it. I suggest, use the `track by $index` for no repeat options

```
<option value="{{option.Value}}" ng-repeat="option in ListOption track by $index">
 {{option.Name}}
</option>
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to repeat the `<select>`

Comment: it doesn't repeat the select. it repeats the `<options>` tag.

Comment: No, that's not how `ng-repeat` works. It repeats the element that you set it on, not it's children

Comment: Still not your friend, it still defaults to the first one <option value="? object:null ?"></option>

Comment: it does with the `{{option.Value}}`??

Comment: yeah, you're right. I forget it. ok, move it to the `option` tag but change the `ListOption` for the `option`. i still recommend use the track by index

Comment: I understand but what i want to be when the default load will select the Value is 0 and Name is Car, do you have any way to help me?

Comment: if you want to charge a default value when loaded the state. you must set your `Category` model the value you need for.  But, I recommend do that on your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is that you used the main array to get value instead of iterable option object. Actually, this should work:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Category" ng-model="Category">
<option ng-repeat="option in ListOption" value="{{option.Value}}">
 {{option.Name}}
</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No. `ListOption` is the List. he needs to show the `option` name

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to change ListOption to the option for the Name too.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpfull :)

### VIEW

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-options="list.Name for list in ListOption" data-ng-model="selectedValue">
```

### MODEL

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log) {
$scope.ListOption = [];
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "0", Name: "Car" });
$scope.ListOption.push({ Value: "1", Name: "House" });
$scope.selectedValue = [];

$scope.selectedValue = $scope.ListOption[0];
```

});